# How I Can Create a Yeoman or Bower repository in Nexus

Tags: javascript, yeoman, bower, nexus

Hi we have an Internal Nexus Repository for our JS artifacts

How can we get the same type of Repository for Bower.io, Yeoman.io, or any other package manager beside NPM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no support for bower repositories in Nexus. We are gathering interest for support [in this issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-6884), so it would be great if you could comment there and express your interest and use case.

In terms of Yeoman - it just uses NPM and/or Bower so there is no separate support necessary as far as I understand.